# Автоматическое заполнение таблицы html

Tags: php, веб-программирование

Здравствуйте! Данный вопрос меня очень интересует, хоть я пока и не нуждаюсь в этом в своем проекте (На будущее, так сказать).

Привожу пример: Пользователь заливает на сайт какой-нибудь файл, и он автоматически показывается в таблице на ряду с другими загруженными файлами.

Таблица, допустим, уже сделана на html. Прошу помочь подтолкнуть на реализацию данной идеи. Лучше уж знать сейчас, чем потом мучиться.

Если будет слишком тяжко,  я зайду на фриланс, но только если сам не смогу разобраться с этим.

Answer (score 2):

Ваша таблица должна генерироваться динамически и показывать все загруженные файлы.

Если файлы при загрузке регистрируются в каком-то месте (например, в БД),
должен формироваться соответствующий запрос к этой базе данных, и на основе полученного ответа должна формироваться таблица.

Если же файл не регистрируется нигде, а просто размещается в каталоге,
то вам нужно генерировать таблицу на основе файлов из этого каталога.
Список файлов вы можете получить  с помощью функции `glob`:

Пример:

```
<?php
foreach (glob("*.txt") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename size " . filesize($filename) . "\n";
}
?>
```

В этом примере мы выводим просто список, не таблицу. Если вы хотите получить таблицу, вам нужно использовать соответствующие тэги разметки (table, tr, td).

Подробнее о функции `glob`:

- http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php (англ.)

Кроме всего прочего, нужно иметь в виду, что существует уже большое количество готовых файловых менеджеров, написанных на PHP. Они, как правило, обладают довольно развитым функционалитетом, работают из коробки и легко подвергаются расширению и модификации. В некоторых случаях, возможно, проще использовать какой-то из них в качестве основы, и просто добавить необходимые функции.

Примеры такого рода менеджеров:

- http://phpfm.sourceforge.net/ (англ.)
- http://extplorer.sourceforge.net/ (англ.)
- https://github.com/simogeo/Filemanager (англ.)

Посмотреть на пример одного из них (последнего) в действии можно здесь:

- http://fm.linea21.com/

Comment: Спасибо большое. еще назрел вопрос из вашего ответа: В чем разница между регистрацией файлов в БД и простого размещения? Что может повлечь собой простое размещение файла, и что безопаснее?

Comment: Загрузка файла может сопровождаться каким-то его дополнительным описанием: вводом ключевых слов, указанием автора, источника и др. Всю эту информацию в таком случае вам нужно будет где-то запомнить. Возможно, в будущем вы захотите как-то использовать эту информацию — например, категоризировать файлы по какому-то критерию или выполнять поиск по ключевым словам. Здесь очень целесообразно рассмотреть вопрос использования БД. Если же вы просто хотите сделать тупое файлохранилище, а-ля FTP-сервер с web-интерфейсом, вам может хватить и просто сохранения файла без всяких БД

Comment: Тогда конечно первый способ гораздо целесообразно использовать. Спасибо за ответ, я запомню это на будущее :)

Comment: Не факт, потому что иногда нужно просто управление файлами. Добавил в ответ существенное дополнение по поводу существующих файловых менеджеров